# Forcing a refresh in force:recordData

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-data-service

force:recordPreview had a ignoreExistingAction attribute that would force a server trip. I have an issue right now where I have two components:

1. Comp A - Contains a list of sObjects, saves/updates using custom code.
2. Comp B - Single component with force:recordData, that will display details from one of the records in the Component A's list.

Right now, if CompA saves a record, and ComponentB had loaded the the record in question at any point, subsequent inits of ComponentB draw from the stale cache.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried [force:refreshView](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_refreshView.htm)?

Comment: yes. The problem is this on the homepage and that causes the whole page to refresh, which I don't want.

Comment: Supposedly, you can use `reloadRecord` on a force:recordData, but that might be a winter 18 thing, since I can't seem to get it working in my dev org.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

ok - reloadRecord takes 2 undocumented arguments

```
reloadRecord(skipCache, callback)
```

so you can just do a

```
cmp.find('recordData').reloadRecord(true)
```

on init, or whenever you need.

Comment: If you do this on onInit, how do you prevent recursive behavior of endlessly reloading itself?