# Lightning:recordform doesnt display record data

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Lightning:recordForm doesnt work, recordid is passed correctly but no field data is being displayed. PFB my code for lightning component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome" controller="OpportunityMachineViewController">  

    <aura:attribute name="sObjectInfo" type="Opportunity"/>

    <aura:attribute name="fieldsArray" type="List" default="[FirstName,LastName]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>  
    {!v.recordId}

<lightning:recordForm recordId="{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="Opportunity"

mode="readonly" fields="{!v.fieldsArray}"/>

</aura:component>
```

Comment: How are you setting `{!v.recordId}`?

Comment: I have not written anything in controller yet. Component code has been posted in question. When im printing V.recordId on component it's being set correctly.

Comment: My mistake you are setting `recordId` using `force:hasRecordId`. I suspect the issue is caused by a delay in the `recordID` value being set. Try hardcoding the `recordID` and you'll find it works, if this is the case, you will need to [force a refresh](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/193206/forcing-a-refresh-in-forcerecorddata)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried below and it works:

```
    <aura:attribute name="sObjectInfo" type="Opportunity"/>

    <aura:attribute name="fieldsArray" type="List" default="['Name','Description']"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" default="00641000007Tx2gAAC"/>  

    <lightning:recordForm recordId="{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="Opportunity"

                          mode="readonly" fields="{!v.fieldsArray}"/>

</aura:component>
```

**Potential Failure Points:**

1. fieldsarray - check if those fields exist in opportunity object and syntax

2.Check if the running user has access to opportunity

Comment: Thanks a Lot! It worked with the change in fieldsArray